# How can I give access/whitelist facebook crawler to view my web app content, using asp.net mvc?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC project with individual user accounts login in place. I want to integrate my application with facebook open graph. Facebook asks me to whitelist or allow access facebook crawler to view content without logging in. Here is what facebook officially asks for:

> The Facebook crawler needs to be able to access your content in order
>   to scrape and share it correctly. Your pages should be visible to the
>   crawler. If you require login or otherwise restrict access to your
>   content, you'll need to whitelist our crawler. You should also exempt
>   it from DDoS protection mechanisms.

I just want to know is there any workaround for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is for access to be allowed; you generally need to *blacklist*, not the other way around. All Facebook is saying here is that if your content is protected somehow *and* you actually want Facebook to be able to see that content anyways, then you need to simply allow the Facebook crawler to bypass whatever protection is in place.

However, there's no one simple answer for this. It's up to you to determine what protections if any you need to bypass and how to bypass it will depend on what the protection is. For something like `Authorize`, for example, you may need to create a custom attribute that looks for the crawler IP (I would not use the crawler's UA string as if some one figures out what you're doing, they could easily spoof that and gain access to protected areas of your site). Then, you could go ahead and treat it as authorized, even though there's no logged in user.

Comment: Thank you Chris! I appreciate this.